# Anonymous Authentication Identity Win 2012 r2 security

Tags: php, iis, authentication, anonymous

I have a web app that uses PHP on the back-end, and the PHP executes powershell scripts to reset AD passwords through system calls.

EX:

```
 shell_exec("powershell.exe -file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\script.ps1 -param $var")
```

In order for me to get this to work I had to set the Anonymous Authentication user to run as an account with permissions to reset AD passwords. I did a bit of googleing about it and didn't find anything explicitly about not giving the Anonymous Authentication these kinds of rights but my gut instinct tells me this is a security problem. It works perfectly, however, and I'd like to keep it that way if I can. But I'd like to know whether or not this is a large security issue or horrible practice before I publish it.

Comment: Seems like a horrible practice. If nothing you could create a separate account to only reset the AD passwords. No other rights on the system. Anonymous Authentication  should not have many any way, but. Also, the account you create could perform the reset on the backend without having web access rights.